# File upload with laravel 5 and image intervention

Tags: laravel-5, imagemagick, intervention

I tried to use [image intevention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installatio) with laravel 5 to upload images and resize..
but i have this error message:

NotSupportedException in Driver.php line 18:
ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation.

> installation:
>   require intervention/image
>
> config/app.php

```
'providers' =>[
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider']

'aliases' => [
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
]
```

then my controller:

```
    public function postUpload(){

        //$imagen = Input::file('image');
        $imagen = Request::input('imagen1');
        // create an image manager instance with favored driver
        $manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick'));

        // to finally create image instances
        $image = $manager->make('public/'.$imagen)->resize(300, 200);
    }
```

then my view:

```
     {!! Form::label('imagen1', 'Imagen principal' , ['class' => "col-md-4 control-label"]) !!}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="imagen1">
                        </div>
```

then..Publish configuration in Laravel 5:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --  provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

I dont know if i have to install ImageMagick, because i have the same problem to upload with GD driver.

Comment: You will need to check 2 things. one is imagemagik installed. you can see by checking on commandline "which convert" and if you don't know, just install it, with with yum or apt-get, which ever OS you are using. also you will need to have installed php-imagick - if you have say php56 installed you would need to install php56-imagick.